# C++ How to simulate special key strokes (alt+numepad)

Tags: c++, windows, input, keyboard, virtual-keyboard

I'm working on a project where I have to send certain text into specific webpage (in Chrome) but I can't send it directly or copy&paste it. The solution I came up with is keyboard bot - I use virtual keys to do the job, but in that text I have special sign "↔" (Alt+numepad2+numepad9) and I can't make it with virtual keys. I'll be greatful for any working solution. I did try various methods I found but nothing worked, if I simulate only alt press and manually type on numepad it works, but not when program does it.
Here's my code:

```
#define WINVER 0x0500
#include <windows.h>
int main()
 { 
    INPUT typ;
    typ.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    typ.ki.wScan = 0;
    typ.ki.time = 0;
    typ.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

        //Time to select window  
        Sleep(5000);
        // Press the "X" key
        typ.ki.wVk = 'X';
        typ.ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
        SendInput(1, &typ, sizeof(INPUT));

        // Release the "X" key
        typ.ki.wVk = 'X';
        typ.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        SendInput(1, &typ, sizeof(INPUT));

        // Press the "Alt" key
        typ.ki.wVk = VK_MENU;
        typ.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY|0; 
        SendInput(1, &typ, sizeof(INPUT));
        //Sleep(3000);
        // Press the "2" key
        typ.ki.wVk = VK_NUMPAD2;
        typ.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY|0; 
        SendInput(1, &typ, sizeof(INPUT));

        // Release the "2" key
        typ.ki.wVk = VK_NUMPAD2;
        typ.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY|KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        SendInput(1, &typ, sizeof(INPUT));

        // Release the "Alt" key      
        typ.ki.wVk = VK_MENU;
        typ.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY|KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        SendInput(1, &typ, sizeof(INPUT));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `SendInput()` supports a `KEYEVENTF_UNICODE` flag for keyboard events so you can send Unicode codepoints instead of virtual key codes. You should use `KEYEVENTF_UNICODE` for text chars and omit it for hardware events

Comment: While the unicode code works in notepad, the webpage I send the message to answers me with error "Invalid lenght of text group value. Lenght is 29. Between 1 and 20 is allowed"

Comment: I can't comment on that without seeing your updated code that is sending keystrokes to the web page. Also, why are you resorting to `SendInput()` at all instead of using UI Automation or the browser's own DOM API?

Comment: The updated part of code is in answer bellow. I just made what I can with my current knowladge so if You can recommand me a good tutorial with examples for these I'd be greatful. The whole purpuse of program is to catch string send from machine (SYSMAC) which scans barcodes and add it to database which is in webpage and...I have limited input options thanks to it. Before the machine everything was done manualy and the webpage owner refuses to change it's code

Comment: you don't HAVE to use the web page to insert into the database. Check if the web server offer a REST based API for that. If it does not, you can always use an HTTP client library to interact with the web server similarly to how a web browser does behind the scenes. Either approach would give you better control over submitting Unicode data to the web server in code without resorting to UI manipulation

Answer (score 0):

If someone needs the unicode key press

```
// Press a unicode "key"
typ.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;
typ.ki.wVk = 0;
typ.ki.wScan = 0x2194; // HEX UNICODE 
SendInput(1, &typ, sizeof(INPUT));

// Release key
typ.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
SendInput(1, &typ, sizeof(INPUT));
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
    keybd_event(0x12, MapVirtualKey(0x12, 0), 0, 0); //Alt press
    keybd_event(0x62, MapVirtualKey(0x62, 0), 0, 0); // Numpad2 press
    keybd_event(0x62, MapVirtualKey(0x62, 0), KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0); //Numpad2 relese
    keybd_event(0x69, MapVirtualKey(0x69, 0), 0, 0); // Numpad9 press
    keybd_event(0x69, MapVirtualKey(0x69, 0), KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0); //Numpad9 relese
    keybd_event(0x12, MapVirtualKey(0x12, 0), KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0); // Alt relese
```